# Change percentage formats based on value

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

I'm currently working on building some reports and need help getting a percentage format to display correctly in the MS Word mail merge I am doing.

There are two different ways the percentages need to be formatted. The person can either have a 100% or some variation of a percentage like so: 19.25%. I only want decimal places if the percentage isn't 100%

I have tried setting the format as follows: 
{ MERGEFIELD Staff_Earned # "#0.##%;#0%;} but it isn't working.

I've also tried
{ MERGEFIELD Staff_Earned # "#0.00%}

It either only shows the rounded percentage or adds extra 0's on 100%. Can someone help me?

Comment: What does { MERGEFIELD Staff_Earned } output without any formatting?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - there isn't sufficient information in the question. What is the data source? How is the content in question formatted in the data source? What results are you getting, exactly, with what you've tried? "It isn't working" doesn't tell us anything useful. Show some examples of expected results vs. what you're getting for a few data points.